# Cannot infer Payment Method Mercadopago Integración

Tags: flutter, api, backend, mercadopago

I'm trying to generate a card token with the MercadoPago API, specifically using the resource https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/card_tokens, with the following JSON in the request:

```
{
  "cardNumber": "4509953566233704",
  "email": "test@test.com.ar",
  "cardholder": {
    "name": "APRO"
  },
  "expirationYear": "2025",
  "expirationMonth": "11",
  "securityCode": "123"
}
```

The web service responds with the following:

```
{
  **"id": "28e607d8cbceb068e7b99e84c6988216"**,
  "public_key": "public key de test",
  "first_six_digits": "450995",
  "expiration_month": 11,
  "expiration_year": 2025,
  "last_four_digits": "3704",
  "cardholder": {
    "identification": {},
    "name": "APRO"
  },
  "status": "active",
  "date_created": "2023-05-09T01:10:42.346-04:00",
  "date_last_updated": "2023-05-09T01:10:42.346-04:00",
  "date_due": "2023-05-17T01:10:42.346-04:00",
  "luhn_validation": true,
  "live_mode": true,
  "require_esc": false,
  "card_number_length": 16,
  "security_code_length": 3
}
```

But when I try to make the following request to generate a payment in MercadoPago using the resource /v1/payments (POST method):

```
{
  "payer": {
    "entity_type": "individual",
    "type": "customer",
    "first_name": "APRO",
    "last_name": "Test",
    "address": {},
    "email": "pedrito@gmail.com",
    "identification": {}
  },
  "description": "Celular Xiaomi Redmi Note 11S 128gb 6gb Ram Original Global Blue Version",
  "installments": 1,
  "issuer_id": "123456",
  **"token": "28e607d8cbceb068e7b99e84c6988216"**,
  "payment_method_id": "visa",
  "transaction_amount": 100
}
```

The web service responds with:

```
{
  "message": "Cannot infer Payment Method",
  "error": "bad_request",
  "status": 400,
  "cause": [
    {
      "code": 2131,
      "description": "payment methods inference error",
      "data": "09-05-2023T05:13:19UTC;e8d91d35-ea9a-4af9-993c-d08a4c058190"
    }
  ]
}
```

After searching the internet, I found out that Cannot infer Payment Method refers to attempting to pay with a card that was originally selected for another option, for example, entering a credit card number for the debit card option.

Do you have any solution for this issue? I have searched the internet but cannot find an answer.